# Please fix spam detection

Tags: bug, status-completed, spam

Today , I was editing a question and apparently there were some new changes in place for spam detection. Definitely good news . . . except that spam detection is broken:

[image]
[image]

Out of all the words that there are for spam, the system latched onto "According" and "Wikipedia". IMHO it is overboard and puts sticks into wheels of users who are trying to write well-researched answers with sources. Please revise the spam filter, as this is . . . how should I put it . . .doesn't do what it's supposed to do.

On a side note, I propose a rep-cap feature added to spam filter. Users like myself - with over 10k of reputation - can be sufficiently trusted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

CJK characters were blocked on Ask Ubuntu in response to a wave of spam. The message is intentionally misleading, to discourage the spammers from just working around it.

I've removed the block for now... If the site is deluged with spam, it may be re-added.

Comment: isn't it feasible to disable spam detection on 10k+ users?

Comment: yeah, but for this particular check it isn't currently implemented.

Comment: @Dan even 100 rep would probably be safe.

Answer (score 5):

According to Wikipedia, the llama is a quadruped.

Edit: That posted fine. I wonder if this was a temporary bug that is now fixed.

Comment: I suppose so.  I've tried editing one of my posts from yesterday, and didn't have any error messages. Weird . . .

Comment: OK, I reproduced it again, while trying to add “According to Wikipedia” at the top. This seems to occur only for this  post : http://askubuntu.com/a/816051/295286  Can this have something to do with amount of links or having a screenshot ?

Comment: @MarkKirby So, I got the error again, when I put in "Test" , and it threw error for "Test states" . So basically whatever word is at the top it gets recognized as spam.

Comment: I think it's that post in general, not the words it's claiming are spam. It looks like spammy. Many links. Other languages. A `.cn` domain. I know it's total ham here but a lot of spam will contain those.

Comment: Seems like it has to do with the partial quote I've pasted there  in Chinese. As soon as I paste it back, error returns . A few words go by alright, but a passage gets the error